# arduino due: how to read more than one byte at a time in serial uart with tfmini liar sensor

Tags: arduino-due, uart

I'm trying read tfmini lidar sensor from arduino due board with uart. Here i can read only one byte at a time using serail.read() method but i need to read 9 byte at a time and store it in array. Means i don't want to repeat loop again and again to store byte by byte.

Comment: Serial is only one byte. If something send multiple bytes then you have to read each individual byte.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readbytesuntil/

Comment: Majenko, That means i have to repeat the loop untill a would not get the last data!!!

Comment: You would have to repeat *a* loop. Not necessarily "the" loop. But it depends how "blocking" you are happy for your code to be.

Comment: Do we have any UART interrupt in arduino due board?

Comment: Yes but it is being used by the UART reception code. You do know the bytes get placed into a buffer, and you can read them any time you like, don't you?

Comment: No, i don't know, may you please share UART reception code to read data from the UART interrupt.